# Is There an Alternative Method to Mimic the Behavior of an Anchor Link/Target Pseudo-Class?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, anchor, href

**Original Post:**

Is it possible for `onclick` within an `<a>` tag to call an anchor link, just as `href` does?

In the snippet below, I have `<a href="#view">` applied to all images, and `<a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!">` as a return URL once each image is closed from lightbox view.

Ideally, I would rather have the anchors prompted where they would not create any sort of extension to the page's URL.

So after clicking `<a href="#view">`, it adds on to the page's URL like so:

`http://ARANDOMURL.com/page#view`

And then once lightbox window is closed, the URL then displays:

`http://ARANDOMURL.com/page#!`

Then you have to click the browser's back button however many extra times before you can return to the actual previous page...

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

**Latest Update (Resolved):**

This is working now, thanks to NetMage's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178067/4333321):

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!--lightbox-->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but you can navigate using `location`,

Comment: @SLaks So I've removed href and applied `<a onclick="location.href='#view'">` to open the lightbox function, and then `<a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" onclick="location.href='#!'; return false;"></a>` to close it, but it is still producing the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample, it seems you are using the CSS `:target` selector to handle displaying and hiding the lightbox. The `:target` selector is applied to the target element of the current URL, so the changes don't take affect if you don't modify the URL.

Instead of modifying the URL, change all the `:target` selectors in your CSS to be `.target` selectors.

Then, in your event handlers:

```
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
    var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
    $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
    $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

Now, when you click an image, the CSS style class `target` is added to the `#view` element, which causes it to appear, and when you click the Close box, the `target` class is removed, and they disappear.

You no longer need to change the URL or `href`, so you can remove the anchor tags for `#view` and the close onclick to set back to `#!`.

Sample new Lightbox instance:

```
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Change to close lightbox control:

```
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. So I would replace `anchortag` with `view` then? what about when I close the lightbox window?

Comment: You would need to remember where you came from and scroll back - I would store the element you clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. Would you be able to apply this solution to the snippet I've provided? I can't seem to figure out how to implement it properly.

Comment: Then I can mark it as the solution once it is working.

Comment: I re-write my answer know that I understand what you are attempting. See what you think.

Comment: So you are saying that in my CSS I should rewrite `.customlightbox:target` to: `.customlightbox.target`, (and all of the other :target elements preceding)?

Comment: Ok, so I have just updated the snippet from my original post. I applied your suggested solution, but it still requires me to click the browser back history button however many times the lightbox was opened... Which I guess was the main issue to begin with.

Comment: It should not be doing that. Did you take out all the anchor tags for `#view` and the assigment to href for `#!` ?

Comment: But, if I did that, what would the `$('#view').addClass("target");` and `$('#view').removeClass("target");` be for, if the `#view` anchor didn't exist?

Comment: There should be no `#` in your page when done. Don't remove the `id = "view"` from your `div`, remove the **anchor** tags that reference `#view`. I added some sample changes.

Comment: Ok, I think it is working now, once I modified the snippet again. Can you take a look to make sure it matches your suggestion?

Comment: Looks the same as mine.